# How to set up a load test based on virtual users using individual specific virtual machine names

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, msloadtest

I have a load test that I need to create.  This load testing has to simulate 300+ virtual users login into a web app and performing some different functionalities.  Now the issue at hand is the login for the web app is configured using a users machine name and there credentials.  The main problem that exist is simulating the virtual user's machine.
ie ...If virtual user 001 logs into the web app.  The web app on the back end will look to see what machine is set up with virtual user 001. That machine name is tied to there credentials.

I know currently when we create a load test in Microsoft and set up the number of virtual user we want the agent to run and create, but the issue is even though we can run it using ip switching to simulate calls from different IP addresses it doesnt adress the issue with physical machine name its just based on request i believe.  I dont know if there is a way to ensure that there is a 1 to 1 between virtual users and machine name and how to get the machine name that, the virtual user will be using to run the test.

I've also read about deploying our load agents using ARM template?  I don't know how that would look or could be done.  I would like the solution to use Microsoft existing technology whether its on prem or in cloud.  We would like to stay on Microsoft path so we can get the report that gets generated after running the load test that tells us response time and all other included information.

The solution has to include a way for us to create a relationship between
1. Virtual User and a machine name.
2. We would like to create a format for naming the virtual machine name like exampl. vmagt-0001 .... vmagt-1000 .  That way we can set up these virtual machines on the web app config so when the 
agents run the virtual users it will use the associated virtual machines.

Comment: I think we need more details of the association between user-id and machine-name. What exactly does the server do? Have you recorded a test with a user on the correct computer? Have you recorded a test with a user on the wrong computer? What do both test do and/or not do?

Comment: It is common in performance testing with multiple users to create users specifically for the purpose of testing. Can you create multiple users that all use the same computer, the computer running the tests?